# Two div in a line and other two on the next line

Tags: html, css, css-float

i am try css to display div in line

this is my html

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
  </div>
   <div id="main_new">
    <div id="div1_new">div1_new</div>
    <div id="div2_new">div2_new</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

this is my css

```
#div1{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
#div2{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
  float: right;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7mJX/46/)

here i am set only first div sub two div in one line 
but i want to set another two div same as this
**div1_new is in below on div1
div2_new is in below on div2**
thanks.

Comment: hey can you add a picture or screenshot of your desired result what exactly do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/J7mJX/47/
You need to apply a clearfix

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS for your html:

```
#div1, #div1_new {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}

#div2, #div2_new {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
  float: right;
}

#main, #main_new {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

Changed the id names to classes instead. I also put a br tag to separate the divs!

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="divs1">div1</div>
    <div class="divs1">div2</div>
  </div>
    <br/>
   <div id="main_new">
    <div class="divs2">div1_new</div>
    <div class="divs2">div2_new</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(`display:inline-block;` is the code you probably were missing)
And here's the adjusted Css:

```
.divs1{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
    width:70px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.divs2{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
  width:70px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's a fiddle link to help:

http://jsfiddle.net/Anicefry/t3Lmw/

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ugktn/

```
<body>
  <div id="left-col">
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div1_new</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-col">
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div2_new</div>
  </div>

   <div id="main_new">
    middle text   
   </div>
</body>
```

Css:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#left-col{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
#right-col{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify your desired width for all div.Include this in all

> width:100px;
>   float:left;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use less divs :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div {width:50%; float:left}
            div.divRed { background-color:red; }
            div.divGreen { background-color:Green; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class='divRed'> div1 </div>
        <div class='divGreen'> div2 </div>
        <div class='divGreen'> div1 new </div>
        <div class='divRed'> div2 new </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before first container ends

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/T5Tdn/2/)**

```
#main {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#main_new {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
#div1{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
}
#div2{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
}
#div1_new{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2_new{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your actual code and use css calculation do this in your css:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#main{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
#main_new{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
  float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7mJX/51/

or if you want them side by side add a width to the body:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 113px;
}
#main{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
#main_new{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
  float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7mJX/52/

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id="main-div">
<div style="float:left">div1</div>
<div style="float:right">div2</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-div1">
<div style="float:left">div3</div>
<div style="float:right">div4</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#main-div,.main-div1{
  width:90px;
}
```